# Efficient way to find point on a svg stroke closest to the current mouse point?

Tags: javascript, svg

As user moves mouse cursor near the strokes of svg path I would like to display a circle on a stroke at the point closest to current mouse point. The only solution comes to mind is to manually parse SVG data and find closest point checking all segments of the path. Implementation of this is quite involving and potentially too slow.
I could draw transparent stroke on top of current stroke with larger width and use SVG hit testing capabilities to detect that point is close to the stroke but is there any way to determine corresponding 'central' point of the stroke?

Comment: can you share some code and example what you tried

Comment: I don't have any code to share because I don't have any ideas how to implement this. The only reliable solution I have now is to manually parse path data and check all the segments one by one but I would like to avoid implementing this. I am looking for alternatives maybe utilizing some DOM API which I am not aware of or some tricks which could help.

Comment: what type of path do you have? is it all straight lines, or do you have curves?

Comment: I am looking for general solution - anything supported by `path` element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting, but too involving problem to be solved here.
You will probably need to do some calculations on your own. You might find method [getPointAtLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getPointAtLength) to be useful. If you are comfortable of using some library like D3, you can find some helping functions there as well. I think very good approach to solve this is to segment your path and use Voronoi tessellation. You can find the code and demo here:

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/8027835

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess there is no other way around and have to use some computational approach...

Comment: I find it a bit unfair to say "unlikely you'll find DOM API helpful for this", as the D3 solutions are all based on SVGGeometryElement.getPointAtLength(). All Mike Bostock does is to increase the efficiency of the search algorithm applied to points found with that API:

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer, have not found anything better.